# Azure Database sync failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to sync my on-premises SQL database with Azure SQL database.The first time was successes. However, when I tried to modify my sync database structure(delete the unnecessary tables from sync group), it couldn't sync. The error was :

Failed to perform data sync operation: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ObjectModel.SyncGroupNotReadyForReprovisionException' was thrown.

I searched it on Google but I couldn't find a solution for that. How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Your sync database structure has changed, that's why the sync stopped and the error happens.

SQL Data Sync lets users synchronize data between Azure SQL databases and on-premises SQL Server in one direction or in both directions. One of the current limitations of SQL Data Sync is a lack of support for the replication of schema changes. Every time you change the table schema, you need to apply the changes manually on all endpoints, including the hub and all members, and then update the sync schema.

If you are making a change in an on-premises SQL Server database, make sure the schema change is supported in Azure SQL Database.

For more details, please see [Automate the replication of schema changes in Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-update-sync-schema). This article introduces a solution to automatically replicate schema changes to all SQL Data Sync endpoints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to give my two cents about this "automate" solution, I personally implemented that approach which seems very smart. But if you work with DacPacs, you might have pre-post deployment scripts which might alter the data in your tables, before applying structural changes, those are not included in this approach, and will cause failure anyways.